# Google chrome how to flip horizontally as permanent without extensions

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have 60fps site (half webrtc, half webgl and iframes) which needs to be completely flip horizontally for mirror view (some physical hardware screen compatibility related).

How can i do following screenshot like `.scale` in whole page starting from `<body>` to all element in that page?

[image]

Or is there any Google Chrome command line argument to by default flip horizontally as permanently?

Comment: If some of your users need to flip their screen, don't you think they'll do at some os level ? I don't think you've got to take care of this into your webapp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `scaleX`.

```css
body {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<p>I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts.</p>
<p>Here they are, standing in a row.</p>
```

Comment: Will this work for mouse cursor? or the mouse cursor will be in wrong position?

Comment: @YumYumYum For that, you'll want to look into the `cursor: <uri>` property. That might be more than can be managed cross-OS though, since OSX/Windows/Linux will have different cursor appearances.